# Eclipse DDMS File Explorer File uploading but not showing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, ddms

Eclipse DDMS File Explorer File uploading for gallery but not showing in android emulator gallery. Any idea please help I am new in android.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a file via DDMS does not cause the `MediaStore` to recognize the file, and it is the `MediaStore` index that is used by the `Gallery` app.

From code, you can use `MediaScannerConnection` to force a re-scan. Or, restart the emulator, as external storage is re-scanned on each startup.

BTW, I am assuming that you uploaded the file to some place on external storage (e.g., `/mnt/sdcard/`).

Comment: thanks I am uploading file for gallery apps in emulator through eclipse DDMS. I am pushing file in as you mentioned /mnt/sdcard/ but my problem is files are not showing in gallery apps. I am trying to learn implicit activity that's why I need this. please help me.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA: "but my problem is files are not showing in gallery apps" -- please re-read the first and second paragraphs of my answer.

Comment: I have restarted my emulator but it hasn't worked. I am new in android so i don't know how to force rescan by code. Thanks.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA: If restarting the emulator does not work, then I do not know what to tell you. Either you are not successfully uploading the file, or the file is in an unreadable format, or the emulator is having issues.

Comment: thanks. I have restarted emulator but not eclipse. I am just uploading 2 pic for gallery. I don't have any idea why it's not working.

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA I had the same problem, but the files were there after restarting the virtual phone itself, not just launching from the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with this so I am taking the time to provide an answer.

Uploading  media to emulator:

1. After you upload the media to the emulator click on the Dev Tools icon.
2. Then go to Media Provider
3. Press the Scan SD Card button.

Now, your images should show.